# ng-click inside ng-repeat to point to sibling div not all divs in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ok, first off horrible title, hopefully i can explain it better here.
so I have an ng-repeat, inside this repeat there is a div that holds a button and another div. I would like the button to only effect the div next to it. Currently the button effects all the divs inside the loop.

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in menu" ng-show="!$first">
    <div class="col-md-2" back-img="item.img">
        <div ng-controller="buttonController">
            <button ng-click="fadeIt('redbox')">click to fade</button>
            <div class="redbox">fade me</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I looked at ng-class, but I wasn't able to figure out how to make the 'redbox' class change it's value to incorporate the ng-repeat iteration (so 'redbox1' 'redbox2' etc).  I also tried giving the redbox div item.title hoping that it would iterate that way.  no luck. basically I want the button to only change it's sibling div.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get at the index of an element in a ng-repeat with `$index` so you could change the html to:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in menu" ng-show="!$first">
    <div class="col-md-2" back-img="item.img">
        <div ng-controller="buttonController">
            <button ng-click="fadeIt('redbox' + $index)">click to fade</button>
            <div class="redbox{{$index}}">fade me</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And probably use id rather than class since it is a unique identifier.

Comment: @ZackArgyle yeah this seems like a bit of a hack to use the class. Not sure how the fadeIt function works though

Comment: Year, use id selector will make the browser more faster to get the dom.  : )

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I will try this tonight. I used class originally because each div wasn't going to change it's styles etc, but now I am changing the way it works and since I need them to be unique, ID is the way to go thanks again.

Comment: So, I've just tested this, technically it didn't work, but I gave you the answer because it's basically right. what wasn't working is that $parent needed to be added to $index so redbox{{$parent.$index}}. thanks again!

Comment: @tomo Not sure why you need $parent. I tried it in a jsFiddle and it seems to work fine without $parent: http://jsfiddle.net/robianmcd/tC8uK/ . Also do you need a separate controller for each button? If you can get by with just one controller for the whole view then you won't have to deal with weird nested scope issues like this.

Comment: @rob i mean the $parent seems logical because it's referencing it's parent i guess, i'm still pretty new to angular so sometimes I'm just trying to get something to work (for example bootstrap's angularjs ui component typeahead, but that's another thing), but ya, I can post more of the code when i get home tonight, but it definitely didn't work without $parent. I'm using tweenMax to animate the div's in the loop, but ya I'll post up more of the code tonight.

Comment: @tomo When you have a nested scope it prototypicaly inherits from the parent scope. This mean that when you try to access $index on the child scope javascript sees that it doesn't exist so it automatically looks for it on the parent scope. So you rarely need to use $parent. There are cases where you need to use it though and you have clearly run into one but I think a better solution would be to try and avoid having nested scopes like this whenever possible. When you use $parent your logic can become very susceptible to small changes in your layout.

Comment: ya i didn't like using $parent, and I'm totally open to suggestions on how to improve my code, I'll post up tonight and if anyone is interested in doing a code review great.

Comment: alright here's a plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/us61JXCxQELXmsie4Ell?p=preview

obviously it doesn't run but that's what I'm doing, and it doesn't run without $parent

Comment: @tomo you could try something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/rjjiocoMHrinO8g4mANw?p=preview

Comment: @rob I tried that last night and it worked, except now my tween doesn't run, it does what it does in your example, switch the number, but won't tween. I've tried every scenario I can think of to troubleshoot this.